# I'm unable to de-authorize callback

Tags: facebook, callback

I want to delete record of those peoples who have remove app from their application's list, to do this I have entered that URL where I make a code to delete record of active user from my database in de-authorize callback. But still I'm unable to de-authorize users from by db.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: See [Facebook Deauthorize Callback over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369169/facebook-deauthorize-callback-over-https) for what my original problem really was. Summary: Improper web server configuration on my part.

Original answer was:

One potential problem has to do with https based deauthorize callbacks. At least some SSL certificates are not compatible with the Facebook back end servers that send the ping to the deauthorize callback. I was only able to process the data once I implemented a callback on an http based handler.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check...

- That the URL of your server is visible from facebook's servers (ie not 192.168 or 10.0 unless you've got proper firewall and dns config).
- Try using an anonymous surfing service and browsing to the URL you gave facebook - do you see a PHP Error?
- Increase the loglevel for PHP and Apache/IIS to maximum and see if you get any more information

We can't do much more unless you give us your code...